# Convert timestamp while mapping through unordered list

Tags: reactjs

Here's the Messages component 
I want to convert `message.timestamp` with `toLocaleString()` while mapping through them

How?

```js
function Messages({ messages }) {
  const messagesContainerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollMessagesToBottom();
  }, [messages]);

  const scrollMessagesToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesContainerRef.current) {
      messagesContainerRef.current.scrollTop = messagesContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="messages" ref={messagesContainerRef}>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <img src={profileImage} alt='alt' className='profile-image'/>
            <span className='message-name'>{message.name} <span className='message-timestamp'>{message.timestamp}</span></span>
            <span className='message-text'>{message.text}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

messages prop

```js
[
    {
        text,
        timestamp,
        name
    },
    {
        text,
        timestamp,
        name
    }
]
```

```js
function Messages({ messages }) {
  const messagesContainerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollMessagesToBottom();
  }, [messages]);

  const scrollMessagesToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesContainerRef.current) {
      messagesContainerRef.current.scrollTop = messagesContainerRef.current.scrollHeight;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="messages" ref={messagesContainerRef}>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <img src={profileImage} alt='alt' className='profile-image'/>
            <span className='message-name'>{message.name} <span className='message-timestamp'>{message.timestamp.toLocaleString()}</span></span>
            <span className='message-text'>{message.text}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`message.timestamp.toLocaleString()`doesn't work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You have errors in console or unexpected date format? Does `timestamp` present in all entries of your array?